# Not understanding big O notation O(∑ i=0 n−1 (∑ j=i+1 n (j−i)))=O(∑ i=0 n−1 2 (1+n−i)(n−i))=O(n^3)

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, big-o

Working on the following problem:

> Given a string s, find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters.

I'm using this brute force solution:

```
public class Solution {
    public int lengthOfLongestSubstring(String s) {
        int n = s.length();

        int res = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
                if (checkRepetition(s, i, j)) {
                    res = Math.max(res, j - i + 1);
                }
            }
        }

        return res;
    }

    private boolean checkRepetition(String s, int start, int end) {
        int[] chars = new int[128];

        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            chars[c]++;
            if (chars[c] > 1) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Tbe big O notation is as follows:
[image: O(∑ i=0 n−1 (∑ j=i+1 n (j−i)))=O(∑ i=0 n−1 2 (1+n−i)(n−i))=O(n^3)]

I understand that three nested iterations would result in a time complexity O(n^3).

I only see two sigma operators being used on the start of the formula, could someone enlighten me on where the third iteration comes to play in the beginning of the formula?

Comment: Perhaps you would understand the notation better if instead of `∑ j=i+1 n (j−i)` it was written `∑ j=i+1 n (∑ k=i j 1)`? As in, there is an inner loop from `i` to `j`. They have written it as `(j-i)`, because `∑ k=i j 1` is just `1` added together `(j-i)` times.

Comment: `checkRepetition(s, i, j)` is O(1) time, not j-i, so the entire calculation is wrong (at least practically speaking -- technically it's correct because big-O is an upper bound).

Comment: I've never seen big O notations like that, and frankly hope to never see them again - nobody outside academia would care about such detail. Just stick to the basic flavours O(1), O(log n), O(n), O(n log n), O(n²) etc

Comment: @PaulHankin In what world is a loop from `start` to `end` constant?

Comment: How is this a java question, instead of a [cs.se] question? Stack Overflow is focused on practice, not theory (and while big-O can be useful in practice, Bohemian is spot-on about _how_ it's used in real-world practice; the example here is like adding a bunch of digits after the decimal point of something that's a wild approximation -- it doesn't actually make anything more precise in a practically useful way).

Comment: @Welbog the loop in checkRepetition is terminated when a duplicate character is found (or an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is raised). That happens at the latest after 129 iterations.

Answer (score 1):

The first sum from i=0 to n-1 corresponds to the outer for loop of `lengthOfLongestSubstring`, which you can see iterates from i=0 to n-1.

The second sum from j = i+1 to n corresponds to the second for loop (you could be starting j at i+1 rather than i as there's no need to check length 0 sub-strings).

Generally, we would expect this particular double for loop structure to produce O(n^2) algorithms and a third for loop (from k=j+1 to n) to lead to O(n^3) ones. However, this general rule (k for loops iterating through all k-tuples of indices producing O(n^k) algorithms) is only the case when the work done inside the innermost for loop is constant. This is because having k for loops structured in this way produces O(n^k) total iterations, but you need to multiply the total number of iterations by the work done in each iteration to get the overall complexity.

From this idea, we can see that the reason `lengthOfLongestSubstring`  is O(n^3) is because the work done inside of the body of the second for loop is not constant, but rather is O(n). `checkRepitition(s, i, j)` iterates from i to j, taking `j-i` time (hence the expression inside the second term of the sum). `O(j-i)` time is O(n) time in the worst case because `i` could be as low as `0`, `j` as high as `n`, and of course O(n-0) = O(n) (it's not too hard to show that `checkRepitions` is O(n) in the average case as well).

As mentioned by a commenter, having a linear operation inside the body of your second for loop has the same practical effect in terms of complexity as having a third for loop, which would probably be easier to see as being O(n^3) (you could even imagine the function definition for `checkRepitition`, including its for loop, being pasted into `lengthOfLongestSubstring` in place to see the same result). But the basic idea is that doing O(n) work for each of the O(n^2) iterations of the 2 for loops means the total complexity is O(n)*O(n^2) = O(n^3).